# Cannot install postgres with brew. Get "FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist" no matter what command I try

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I've tried to install postgres 13.1 on my Mac using homebrew.  (Also tried versions 11 & 12 which at one time **were** installed on this Mac, but encountering same error with those versions now).  Am using notes I took from previous installs & of course google/stackoverflow. Tried many things/many times, but always, if I run psql, createuser, createdb (any postgres command), it responds with:

**FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist**

Also tried just creating a postgres user on my Mac to run install from that account; no luck.

Also tried postgresql install from the enterprisedb.com site. That worked, but seems klunky & seems to rely on .sh scripts. Interestingly, got the '*role postgres does not exist*' error after the edb install too, but noticed if I just entered 'postgres' twice on the command line it worked. Example:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres postgres
```

This trick doesn't work tho with the brew install.

Understand I need to create the postgres role, but I can't find a command to do this that doesn't complain that the role doesn't already exist.

Any help would be so so appreciated!

[image: link to screenshot]

Comment: which OS user owns the config file, and/or the data files?  Try using that name as the existing database role.

Answer (score 3):

Most sites documenting postgres install with homebrew said to use commands like:

`psql postgres`
or
`createuser postgres`

Those didn't work for me, but this did:

```
psql -d postgres -U <myUserName>
```

Attaching a screenshot to try to summarize the install experience & what worked:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2KIs.png)

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked for me for PG 14.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```sh
/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql
```

and then:

```sql
CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;
```

?

Comment: Thank you.  Tried /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql but it returned:  -bash: /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql: No such file or directory.   But I think I solved my problem. Sites I've found documenting how to install postgres with homebrew say to use command:  `psql postgres`  but it seems to need to be `psql -d postgres -U <myUserName>`.    (Thank you very much for responding!  This is my very first stackoverflow post.)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This document solved it for me: https://enrq.me/dev/2021/01/13/fix-role-postgres-does-not-exist/

The gist: run `createuser -s postgres -U <os-username>`